# Javascript (asset) missing in browser's sources

Tags: java, groovy, asset-pipeline

I am developing a plugin in Groovy/java and uses asset-pipeline (gradle) to include a javascript as asset. After the build of the Gradle project, the javascript can be seen under ./build/assets/ folder. The script can also be seen in the JAR file within the folder named assets.

However, when I install this plugin into the vendor's application/platform (developed in Java), the javascript is absent from the page when inspecting the sources using Developer Tools in the browser.

I expected to see that script in sources in this path: site\assets\plugin\nameOfPlugin\scriptName.js.

Can somebody tell me why the script is missing?